# Dynamic function name in Graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have the following query

```
const COURSES = gql`
  query(
    $course: Course!
  ) {
    **english**(course: $course) {
      transfers(
        options: {
          desc: ["count_in", "count_out"]
        }
      ) {
        school {
          address
          symbol
          tokenType
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Note the 5th line starting with 'english' so let's say I have 1000 different courses like ['english', 'politics', 'arts', .... 1000th course). How can I make this course name dynamic. I didn't develop the backend so change in schema is not an option for me. how can I avoid duplication by making course name dynamic.

To be clear I want to place variable name at the place of **'english'** at line 5 so that this line can behave like below

```
   english(course: $course) {
   politics(course: $course) {
   art(course: $course) {
   anyCourseName(course: $course) {
```

Update:
I'm calling above query using useQuery and passing parameter $course like below

```
useQuery(
    COURSES,
    {
      variables: {
        course, //this serves as variable $course in above query
      },
    }
  )
```

Comment: What is the `$course` variable? This API seems badly designed.

Comment: @Bergi please check the updated part. thanks

Comment: Well yes of course you're passing something for the variable. But what is the value that you're passing? And what does it mean? Can you share the schema, including descriptions?

Comment: I would've expected `course(name: "english") { … }` or `course(name: $course) { … }`

Comment: I agree that it should be the case but it isn't. I have mentioned the input and desired output in question. any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well you already got two answers that give the desired output. Don't they work?

Comment: i'm just checking those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const COURSES = (c) => gql`
  query(
    $course: Course!
  ) {
    ${c}(course: $course) {
      transfers(
        options: {
          desc: ["count_in", "count_out"]
        }
      ) {
        school {
          address
          symbol
          tokenType
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
const query = COURSES('art')
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this:

```
const course = "english";

const COURSES = gql`
  query(
    $course: Course!
  ) {
    ${course}(course: $course) {
      transfers(
        options: {
          desc: ["count_in", "count_out"]
        }
      ) {
        school {
          address
          symbol
          tokenType
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Or if you have multiple queries:

```js
const courses = [
  "english",
  "politics",
  "art",
  "anyCourseName",
];

const queries = courses.reduce((acc, query) => (
  acc.concat(`${query}(course: $course) {
      transfers(
        options: {
          desc: ["count_in", "count_out"]
        }
      ) {
        school {
          address
          symbol
          tokenType
        }
      }
  }\n`)
), "");

console.log(queries);
```

then use it in your gql:

```
const COURSES = gql`
  query(
    $course: Course!
  )
  {
    ${queries}
  }
`;
```